# use of mobile phone as multimeter

Tags: android

Is it possible to use mobile phone as sensor for measuring conductivity of a medium? My aim is to avoid any external hardware. The two input channels can be used as 3.5mm microphone jack or USB.

Comment: What type of conductivity?

Comment: If it's a fluid: 1. Start a timer on the phone. 2. Drop the phone into the fluid. 3. Use the length of time before the phone dies to calculate the conductivity. 4. Buy a new phone.

Comment: conductivity of water for measurement of TDS (total dissolved solid).

Comment: Play some old classical music from your phone at a very high volume, if someone in a crowd stands up and begins swinging their arm wildly they might be a good Conductor.....

Comment: @VinayakKumar: It may take quite a while until your phone totally dissolves in water...

Comment: By any external hardware i meant, boards like arduino, IOIO or other microcontroller. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the headphone output and the microphone input together. Send a signal on the output and check on the input if the same signal appears.